# How do I get access to my bundle?

Tags: javascript

I have a `script` that I am exporting a single variable:

```
module.exports = {
    hello: "world"
};
```

I am bundling with `browserify` and then consuming the bundle in my `index.html`

Here is my `html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        console.log(hello);
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting that my variable `hello` is undefined.  I can see the `bundle.js` with my dev tools, so I know it is there.  Why does my `script` in the body not have access to the variables that the `bundle.js` is exporting?

What am I missing here?

Comment: try 'var hello = "world";' in your file

Comment: where is you `bundle.js` file located

Comment: My `bundle.js` is located at the same level as my `index.html`

Comment: Also< I tried to declare `var hello = 'world'` and then exported it, but that didn't help.

Comment: what do you mean by "exported it" ?, and if this is the only code you have, this should throw a ReferenceError I guess

Comment: Are you aware that `module.exports` is for Node.js and will not work for browser-side JavaScript?

Comment: As far as I know, this will not work outside a node.js environment without some leg work.

Comment: I am bundling with `browserify`.  I should of explained that piece.

Comment: I just updated the question with the `browserify` info.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

In `CMD` call

> browserify -r ./bundle-module.js:bundle > bundle.js

*bundle-module.js* is your raw module code

*bundle-module.js:bundle* - after-colon "bundle" is what will be used in *require* call

*bundle.js* is browserify-generated code

`HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        var bundle = require('bundle');
        console.log(bundle.hello);
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```